# I am trying to create slide like TikTok using React Ntaive FlatList & pagingEnabled but autometic top margin is added, can anyone help me

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[This is what I see when app loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvTI.jpg)

[This is what happens when I reached to the endstrong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR6oz.jpg)

I am trying to create app using React Native and pagingEnabled, and I want to add swipe up down like TikTok but every time I swipe up some margin constantly added to the top of my container. I don't know why ? Can any one know the reason.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const Home = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, height: height }}>
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
      data={DummyData}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          <ViewComponent
            index={index}
            item={item}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: index % 2 === 1 ? 'dodgerblue' : 'red',
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: height,
    width: width,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginBottom: 10,
  }
  })
```

Comment: you need to set the height of flatlist to height-tabbarheight, and every cell set to the same height as above.